# Theorem 3.40 of Rotman's Homological Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

I'm reading the proof for Rotman's theorem 3.40, the proof is below 
[image]

[image]

Now, I understand everything until the commutative diagram.  Since he didn't label his maps, from the context, I'm guessing that the first two vertical isomorphism between sums are induced by the isomorphism of $FG(P) \cong P$ and the third vertical map is the natural transformation from $FG \to 1_R$.
My question is with the maps above, how do you know the second square on the right is commutative??

The only way I can see the second square being commutative is if the middle vertical map is also a natural transformation from $FG \to 1_R$, but if that is the case, we don't know if that map is an isomorphism though??

I feel like there is something small that I missed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that the functors $F:{}_S\operatorname{Mod} \rightarrow \operatorname{Mod}_R, M \mapsto P \otimes_S M$ and $G:\operatorname{Mod}_R \rightarrow {}_S\operatorname{Mod}, N \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_R(P,N)$ are adjoint. I would guess that the components of the counit of the adjunction (ie of the associated natural transformation $\varepsilon: FG \Rightarrow 1_{\operatorname{Mod}_R}$) are given by the assignment
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
FG(N) = P \otimes_S \operatorname{Hom}_R(P,N) &\overset{\varepsilon_N}{\rightarrow}&N\\
p \otimes f & \mapsto & f(p)
\end{array}$$
which should be the result of the exercise. Now in the case of $N = P$ this is indeed the isomorphism $P \otimes_S S \cong P$.

Now as $F$ is left adjoint and $P$ is projective, both $F$ and $G$ and hence $FG$ is right exact. This means that given a diagram $D:I \rightarrow \operatorname{Mod}_R$ the morphism $\operatorname{colim} FGD(i) \rightarrow FG(\operatorname{colim} D(i))$ induced by the inclusions $FG(\iota_i)$ is an isomorphism.

Now consider the diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\coprod_I P & \rightarrow & \coprod_J P &\rightarrow & N &\rightarrow 0\\
\uparrow\alpha && \uparrow\alpha‘ && \uparrow&&||\\
FG(\coprod_I P) & \rightarrow & FG(\coprod_J P) & \rightarrow & FG(N) & \rightarrow 0\\
\uparrow\beta&&\uparrow\beta‘&&\uparrow\\
\coprod_I FG(P) & \overset{\phi}{\rightarrow} & \coprod_J FG(P) & \rightarrow& FG(N)& \rightarrow 0\\
\end{array}$$
Where the $\alpha$s are the components of the counit $\varepsilon$ at coproducts of $P$ and the $\beta$s are the morphisms induced as above. $\phi$ and $\psi$ are chosen such that the diagram commutes. It remains to check that the composition $\alpha\beta$ is the coproduct of the components of $\varepsilon$ at $P$, since coproducts of isos are isos and $\beta$ is iso aswell, so $\alpha$ will be iso.

For any index $i$ and inclusions $\iota_i: P \rightarrow \coprod_I P$ and $\kappa_i: FG(P) \rightarrow \coprod_I FG(P)$ the diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\coprod FG(P) &\rightarrow &FG(\coprod P) &\overset{\varepsilon_{\coprod P}}{\rightarrow} &\coprod P\\
\kappa_i\uparrow&&FG(\iota_i)\uparrow&&\iota_i\uparrow\\
FG(P) &=& FG(P) &\overset{\varepsilon_P}{\rightarrow}&P
\end{array}$$
commutes (the left square does because the top arrow is the one induced by the $FG(\iota_i)$ and the right square does by naturality of $\varepsilon$). This
shows that $\alpha\beta = \coprod \varepsilon_P$.

Comment: thank you for the answer, if the first two vertical maps are the natural transformation of $FG \to 1_R$, then how would we know that they are isomorphisms though?

Comment: The component of this natural transformation at the point $P$ is given by the line $FG(P) = F(\operatorname{Hom}(P,P) = F(S) = P \otimes_S S \isom P$, so these morphisms are indeed isos...

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm sorry I'm new to category theory, I do see $FG(P) = P \otimes_S S$ is isomorphic to $P$, but then does this imply that the natural transformation $FG \to 1_R$ for $P$ is this isomorphism?

Comment: No worries. I can relate; I am currently struggling with a category theory lecture I attended this semester myself. I added some more details (mostly because you made me unsure I got this right -.-) so please tell me if this sounds more plausible now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed explanation, it was very helpful and sorry I took kinda long to reply, I have to go thru your argument in detail to understand it. I only have one last question, for the bottom commutative diagram, I know the second square commute because of the naturality of $\epsilon$, but how do we know the first square commute?? I assume your top map for $\coprod FG(P) \to FG(\coprod P)$ is the induced isomorphism, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome and right. The top left arrow is the map induced by the inclusions $FG(\iota_i):FG(P)\rightarrow \FG(\coprod P)$. Sorry I forgot to write that.

Comment: I finally understand all of it, thank you so much for your patience and your help. This seems like a lot of work that Rotman skips, I think if he put in some more detail for the reader to check, it would be better.  Btw, I learn something new from your proof as well, before I kept thinking that a functor $ F $ preserves sum just mean $ F( \coprod M_i) \simeq \coprod FM_i $, I did not know that it preserves the map associated with the sum as well.  Thank you again.

Comment: I am glad I could help. In fact my understanding of what it means to preserve colimits has improved by writing my answer, so thank you for the opportunity :)